# How to display TIFF (in form of Byte[]) on Silverlight Image control

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, tiff, libtiff.net

I created a window service to put all of my TIFF files into database and stored them as `Byte[]`.

Now I want to be able to display them through Silverlight Image control

So i use the Converter during binding XAML in order to convert the `Byte[]` to `Bitmap` because the `Image.Source` only accept eitheir URI (I don't have the file stored on server so can't use this method) or `Bitmap`.

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
if (value != null)
{
    ImageGallery imageGallery = value as ImageGallery;
    byte[] imageContent = imageGallery.ImageContent;
    string imageType = imageGallery.ImageType;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageContent))
    {
        bmi.SetSource(ms);
    }
}
return bmi;
```

However, I get the exception at `bmi.SetSource(ms)` because Silverlight only supports JPEG and PNG images.

So I did more research and knew that i should convert the bytes of TIFF to bytes of JPEG or PNG then it will work.

To do that I tried two methods:

- Doing the conversion on server: in my RIA service call, after retrieving the `ImageGallery`, I loop through the available image to convert the bytes of TIFF to the bytes of JPEG.

BUT IT DOESN'T WORK....
Can you tell me where I did wrong?

```
public IQueryable<ImageGallery> GetImageGalleries()
{
    var imageGalleries = this.ObjectContext.ImageGalleries.OrderBy(i=>i.ImageName);
    foreach (ImageGallery imageGallery in imageGalleries)
    {
        if (imageGallery.ImageType == ".tif" || imageGallery.ImageType == ".tiff")
        {
            //Convert the Tiff byte array format into JPEG stream format
            System.Drawing.Bitmap dImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imageGallery.ImageContent));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            dImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            //then convert the JPEG stream format into JPEG byte array format
            byte[] buf = new byte[ms.Length];  
            ms.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            //Changing the format tiff byte[] of ImageGallery to jpeg byte[] 
            imageGallery.ImageContent = buf;
        }
    }
    return imageGalleries;
}
```

- The other solution is to use [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library to convert directly the `Byte[]` of TIFF to `WritableBitmap` directly on Silverlight.

However, after digging through their sample application or using Reflector to see the source code functions, I still can't figure out how to use their library to convert the bytes of TIFF to `WritableBitmap` JPEG (or PNG) because their sample only show the API for using the search the TIFF in a file directory. In my case, I don't have an existing file on server.

Can someone help me how to show the TIFF file on Image control of Silverlight?

I searched the forum but didn't find any solid answer for this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the LibTiff will be the way to go.  Ulitmately the `Tiff.ClientData` accepts a `Stream` that is the tiff data.  If your tiff data really is a `byte[]` then you just need a `MemoryStream` around it.  More likely at some point the `byte[]` is pulled from a stream so you probably don't even need this intermedatory `byte[]` / `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Reference LibTiff.net
2. Add this class:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
   using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;

   namespace CoreTechs.X9
   {
       public static class TiffUtility
       {
           public static Tiff CreateTiff(this byte[] bytes)
           {
               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
               Tiff tiff = Tiff.ClientOpen("in-memory", "r", ms, new TiffStream());
               return tiff;
           }

           public static IEnumerable<WriteableBitmap> ConvertToWriteableBitmaps(this Tiff tiff)
           {
               if (tiff == null)
                   throw new ArgumentNullException("tiff", "tiff is null.");

               short dirs = tiff.NumberOfDirectories();

               for (int i = 0; i < dirs; i++)
               {
                   if (tiff.SetDirectory((short)i))
                   {
                       int tileCount = tiff.NumberOfTiles();
                       int stripCount = tiff.NumberOfStrips();

                       var frameWidthField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH);
                       var frameHeightField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH);
                       var compressionField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION);
                       var xResolutionField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION);
                       var yResolutionField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION);
                       var samplesPerPixelField = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL);

                       int frameWidth = frameWidthField != null && frameWidthField.Length > 0 ? frameWidthField[0].ToInt() : 0;
                       int frameHeight = frameHeightField != null && frameHeightField.Length > 0 ? frameHeightField[0].ToInt() : 0;
                       var compression = compressionField != null && compressionField.Length > 0 ? (Compression)compressionField[0].Value : Compression.NONE;
                       var xResolution = xResolutionField != null && xResolutionField.Length > 0 ? new double?(xResolutionField[0].ToDouble()) : null;
                       var yResolution = yResolutionField != null && yResolutionField.Length > 0 ? new double?(yResolutionField[0].ToDouble()) : null;
                       var samplesPerPixel = samplesPerPixelField != null && samplesPerPixelField.Length > 0 ? samplesPerPixelField[0].ToString() : String.Empty;

                       if (xResolution != null && yResolution == null)
                       {
                           yResolution = xResolution;
                       }

                       var buffer = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
                       tiff.ReadRGBAImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, buffer);

                       var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight);
                       for (int y = 0; y < frameHeight; y++)
                       {
                           var ytif = y * frameWidth;
                           var ybmp = (frameHeight - y - 1) * frameWidth;

                           for (int x = 0; x < frameWidth; x++)
                           {
                               var currentValue = buffer[ytif + x];

                               // Shift the Tiff's RGBA format to the Silverlight WriteableBitmap's ARGB format
                               bmp.Pixels[ybmp + x] = Tiff.GetB(currentValue) | Tiff.GetG(currentValue) << 8 | Tiff.GetR(currentValue) << 16 | Tiff.GetA(currentValue) << 24;
                           }
                       }

                       yield return bmp;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the exension methods like this:

   ```
   byte[] myHappyTiffData = GetMyTiffBytesFromSomewhere();
   WriteableBitmap bmp = myHappyTiffData.CreateTiff().ConvertToWriteableBitmaps().FirstOrDefault();
   myImageControl.Source = bmp;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

We began with LibTiff as a solution for our media manager. I wouldn't recommend it.

As you can see it creates a WriteableBitmap for each page. WB is the most performance hampering, leaking object you can use in Silverlight, so if you got more then 1 single page tiff your app will run out of memory faster then you can say Avada Kedavra.

There are viewers that appearently can load a large multipage tiff without killing your app (and browser and computer), for a decent license fee, but at this point I got nothing that allows you to decode a tiff an extract the pages.

Runner ups:

- http://www.accusoft.com/
- http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage